# Undefined name 'CancelableOperation'

Tags: flutter, dart, cancelableoperation

I'm trying to implement a Flutter solution that uses a CancelableOperation.

However, even though I have imported the dart:async library, CancelableOperation is undefined for me. I am on dart 2.18.6. Is it apart of that dart version?

I would think I should be able to answer that question myself, however, I see no version number when I look at the documentation on pub.dev for the CancelableOperation class.

https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/CancelableCompleter-class.html

I'm at a loss for words as to why I can't find something that simple out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to documentation of the "async" package which has the CancelableCompleter class, but sound like you're importing the builtin `dart:async` library, which is something different.

Try adding the `async` package to your dependencies (https://pub.dev/packages/async/install) and importing as

```dart
import 'package:async/async.dart';
```